# Glide Crashes App on loading an invalid url

Tags: android, android-glide

When I developing the app, accidentally passed an invalid url to Glide. It made my app to crash.

Sharing my code:

```
val file = requestManager.downloadOnly().load(imageUrl).listener(requestListener).submit().get()
```

Sharing the crash log:

```
 java.lang.Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
There was 1 cause:
java.io.FileNotFoundException(https://imageSamples/sampleimage.jgp)
 call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1139)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
 Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
There was 1 cause:
java.io.FileNotFoundException(https://imageSamples/sampleimage.jgp)
 call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
    at com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestFutureTarget.doGet(RequestFutureTarget.java:205)
    at com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestFutureTarget.get(RequestFutureTarget.java:108)
    at com.sample.app.Manager.cacheImage(Manager.kt:69)
    at com.sample.app.Manager.access$cacheImage(Manager.kt:19)
    at com.sample.app.Manager$updateImageCache$1.run(Manager.kt:46)
    at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:254)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        ... 2 more
 Caused by: com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
There was 1 cause:
java.io.FileNotFoundException(https://imageSamples/sampleimage.jgp)
 call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
```

What I did to prevent the app from crash is try-catch. But I am not really happy to use try catch in code.

```
    try {
        val file = requestManager.downloadOnly().load(imageUrl).listener(requestListener).submit().get()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
```

Is there a better way to handle this? Like some API methods from Glide?

Comment: @Zoe: Thanks for the info, will make sure to use the right one in future.

Answer (score 1):

This may cause because of url not found.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException(https://firebaestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fir-config-f8c4e.appspot.com/o/resized.png?alt=media&token=5ac525a2-b195-467b-b52a-7c1619aa158d)
```

Above url `firebaestorage.googleapis.com` may be wrong because of missing `s` in `fireba(s)estorage`

Comment: By adding `s` am able to see image.

Comment: Even if the URL is valid and the image is accessible, It's wise to use try-catch.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 I don't know which library does SunSun use for. But better use Glide's fallback to handle error instead of try catch.

Comment: @Admiral: Thank you for the answer. I know the cause of the crash, what I want to know is how to handle such situation?

Comment: @AdmiralKunkka : providing fallback not works in this case.

Comment: @AdmiralKunkka: - com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0 - this is the library that I am using.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was adding a try-catch block

```
  return try {
            Glide.with(context)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(imageURL)
                .listener(object : RequestListener<Bitmap> {
                    override fun onLoadFailed(
                        e: GlideException?,
                        model: Any?,
                        target: Target<Bitmap>?,
                        isFirstResource: Boolean
                    ): Boolean {
                        Log.e(
                            TAG,
                            "Texture from ResourceID $resourceId could not be Loaded. " +
                                    "Using default Texture"
                        )
                        return false
                    }

                    override fun onResourceReady(
                        resource: Bitmap?,
                        model: Any?,
                        target: Target<Bitmap>?,
                        dataSource: DataSource?,
                        isFirstResource: Boolean
                    ): Boolean {
                        return false
                    }
                })
                .placeholder(DEFAULT_IMAGE)
                .error(DEFAULT_IMAGE)
                .submit()
                .get()
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            return fromResource(DEFAULT_IMAGE)
        }
```